# Minimum of Integral, relation with area

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find the value of $a$ such that $F(a)$ is minimum, where

$$F(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} |\sin x - a\cos x| dx.$$

I want to differentiate the function but the absolute value prevented me from doing so... Please helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I suppose that you should minimize or maximize $$F(a)=\int_{0}^{\beta} (\sin x - a\cos x) dx +\int_{\beta}^{\pi/2} ( a\cos x-\sin x) dx$$ where $\beta=\tan ^{-1}(a)$. Doing so, you have $$F(a)=-2 a \sin (\beta)+a-2 \cos (\beta)+1$$ and replacing $\beta$ by $\tan ^{-1}(a)$, after a few manipulations of trigonometric identities (I let that to you), you will end with $$F(a)=-2 \sqrt{a^2+1}+a+1$$ $$F'(a)=1-\frac{2 a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}$$ that you want to cancel. The only solution of this last equation is $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ for which $F(a)=1-\sqrt{3}$. The second derivative test shows that this point corresponds to a maximum.

Comment: I think the functions must change places in the integral. So  $\int_0^{\beta}a\cos(x)-\sin(x)dx$ and $\int_{\beta}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)-a\cos(x)dx$, or not ?

Comment: @OBDA. You are perfectly correct. Since I did not know in advane (I am too lazy) I wrote that the function had to be minimized or maximized. Then, the second derivative test. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that minimum is reached for non negative $a$ and
$$
F(a)=\int_{0}^{arctg(a)}(sin(x)-acos(x))dx+\int_{arctg(a)}^{\pi /2}(-sin(x)+acos(x))dx
$$